# const and pointers (a node example)

Tags: c++

Could you please tell me why I get this error:

```
source_file.cpp(41) : error C2664: 'void std::vector<Node<int> *,std::allocator<_Ty>>::push_back(Node<int> *const &)' 
                    : cannot convert argument 1 from 'const Node<int> *' to 'Node<int> *&&'
```

when I call the AddChild method?

Here's my class definition/implementation:

```
template<class T>
class Node
{
    private:
        T _value;
        vector<Node*> children;

    public:
        Node(T value);
        Node(const Node<T>& node);
        void AddChild(const Node<T>* node);
        T getValue() const;
        vector<Node<T>*> returnChildren() const;
        ~Node();
};

template <class T>
Node<T>::Node(T value):_value(value)
{
}

template <class T>
Node<T>::Node(const Node& node):_value(node.getValue()), 
                                children(node.returnChildren())
{
}

template <class T>
void Node<T>::AddChild(const Node* node)
{
    children.push_back(node);
}

template <class T>
T Node<T>::getValue() const
{
    return _value;
}

template <class T>
vector<Node<T>*> Node<T>::returnChildren() const
{
    return children;
}

template <class T>
Node<T>::~Node()
{
    for (vector<Node*>::iterator it=children.begin() ; it!=children.end() ; it++)
    {
        delete (*it);
    }
}
```

Comment: `vector<Node*> children;` requires a non `const` pointer. Change the signature of your function: `void AddChild(Node<T>* node);`.

Comment: Because `X *const &` is not the same as `const X *`, the `const` keyword does not target the same thing in the two declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`children` contains pointers-to-non-const.
The `node` parameter is a pointer-to-const.

Those types are incompatible.

Either store pointers-to-const in `children`, or make the `node` parameter a pointer-to-non-const.